# Haskell Webdriver Selenium Firefox headless mode

Tags: haskell

I enjoy using the wonderful [webdriver](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver-0.9.0.1) package. But one thing that's a bit odd is that the Firefox browser type doesn't support commandline options.
Can anyone help how I can run firefox headless mode with commandline options?
I'm guessing I could use firefox profile but after much googling I couldn't find headless mode linked to firefox profile.

```
data Browser = Firefox { -- |The firefox profile to use. If Nothing,
                         -- a default temporary profile is automatically created
                         -- and used.
                         ffProfile :: Maybe (PreparedProfile Firefox)
                         -- |Firefox logging preference
                       , ffLogPref :: LogLevel
                         -- |Server-side path to Firefox binary. If Nothing,
                         -- use a sensible system-based default.
                       , ffBinary :: Maybe FilePath
                         -- |Available after Firefox 52, and required only for Firefox
                         -- geckodriver. Indicates whether untrusted and self-signed TLS
                         -- certificates are implicitly trusted on navigation for the
                         -- duration of the session.
                       , ffAcceptInsecureCerts :: Maybe Bool
                       }
             | Chrome { -- |Version of the Chrome Webdriver server server to use
                        --
                        -- for more information on chromedriver see
                        -- <https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver>
                        chromeDriverVersion :: Maybe String
                        -- |Server-side path to Chrome binary. If Nothing,
                        -- use a sensible system-based default.
                      , chromeBinary :: Maybe FilePath
                        -- |A list of command-line options to pass to the
                        -- Chrome binary.
                      , chromeOptions :: [String]
                        -- |A list of extensions to use.
                      , chromeExtensions :: [ChromeExtension]
                        -- | Experimental options not yet exposed through a standard API.
                      , chromeExperimentalOptions :: Object
                      }
```

Comment: I don't understand: why do you say that firefox does not use command line options? Here on linux `firefox --help` and `man firefox` list several options, including `--headless`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, there's no specific switch built into the Haskell library, so you'll have to use the `additionalCaps` field inside the `wdCapabilities` field of your `WDConfig`, rather than the `browser` field, and include an `args` array inside a `moz:firefoxOptions` aeson object like this:

```hs
firefoxConfig ∷ WDConfig
firefoxConfig = defaultConfig {
    wdCapabilities = defaultCaps {
        additionalCaps = [
            ("moz:firefoxOptions", object [
                ("args", Array (fromList [String "--headless"]))
            ])
        ]
    }
}
```

Anything else undocumented in Haskell that you wish to pass to Firefox will also go there.

This is explained in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions).